# MYSQL. Как лучше реализовать сохранение данных пользователя?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, users

Есть MYSQL в ней есть таблица с именами файлов и ссылками на них, мне надо чтоб сохранялись данных про пользователя какие файлы он скачал. Я думаю наверное при регистрации создавать под каждого пользователя таблицу и в ней сохранять все имена файлов которые он скачал, но я так понимаю что это уж слишком зашкварно в том плане что вроде более 60 000 таблиц создать в mysql нельзя. Есть какие нибудь другие варианты ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего хранить все файлы пользователей в единой таблице, например, `mediafiles`, при этом каждый файл пользователя помечать внешним ключом в котором хранить идентификатор пользователя

Таблица `users`

```
id name
1  Первый
2  Второй
3  Третий
```

Таблица `mediafiles`

```
id user_id path
1  1       img1.jpg
2  1       logo.jpg
3  2       hello.jpg
4  2       logotype.jpg
5  3       my.jpg
```

Если речь об скачивании файлов, тогда лучше завести еще одну таблицу `downloads`, которая свяжет пользователей (`user_id`) и скаченные ими файлы (`file_id`)

Таблица `downloads`

```
id user_id file_id
1  1       27
2  1       1123
3  2       12
4  2       8
5  3       84
```

Comment: А сколько максимум можно в одной таблице сделать записей ?

Comment: @Fasd Все упирается в первичный ключ, для типа INT его размер 4294967296 для типа BIGINT - 18446744073709551615. Превысить их сложно, но если превысите, можно отказаться от числового первичного ключа и перейти на строковый или прибегнуть к составному первичному ключу на базе нескольких столбцов.

Comment: @cheops почему б не выкинуть суррогатный ключ вовсе? Туда ж записи будут **только вставляться**, изменяться не будут.

Comment: @D-side, согласен, можно и такой вариант рассмотреть.